# Benefits of a suspended state in threads?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I'm tyring to answer a question, a professor purposed us.

> Threads usually have states Running, Ready, and Blocked. Suppose we wanted to add a Suspended state to maximize processor utilization through admitting a larger number of threads requiring more memory than available in the process' address space.Does the above make sense? If it does, explain why and explain what benet(s) we obtain. If it doesnot, explain why not.

The suspended state seems pretty stupid to me because synchronization would just be a terrible experience. In any case where you might want to suspend, going into a blocked state is probably a 10x better idea because of this. And on top of that isn't processor already utilized as best as it can be because when one thread gets blocked, another gets scheduled. By putting in a suspend state that you explicitly go into, you are pretty much manually controlling the scheduling. I'm really confused as to what benefits it would provide. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with you, synchronization is not possible until you are not limited to threads start point synchronization. where you just create a thread in suspended state, and allow it to continue only when parent process raises a flag. But apart of this, synchronization is not possible with suspended thread model.
I also think blocking is a better than hanging up thread in suspended queue. Processor is already fully utilized, and It is not really beneficial anyway to put thread in suspended state until you are using it for some special purpose. **Debuggers** use suspended thread state, so that they can alter/break/trace thread's state. This shows exactly how we can use suspended state.
You are right, You are somewhat manually controlling thread's scheduling process and that makes It a terrible idea.